Workflow - Accept or Reject with button action programmatically without logging into Sitecore
I have created a custom email action to send notifications at each workflow step. The email includes details about the item, such as the item path, creation date, and other relevant information.
Additionally, the email contains "Approve" and "Reject" buttons. When a user clicks on either button, the corresponding action (approve or reject) should be executed without requiring the user to log in to Sitecore.
Kindly provide the information.
